# Infinity vs Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, numbers

I understand that `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` has a value of `Infinity`, and `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` has a value of `-Infinity`.

Is there a reason I would use `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` instead of `Infinity`, or `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` instead of `-Infinity`?

<sub>On a related note, are there any cross-browser issues with `isFinite`?</sub>

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## TL;DR

`Infinity` used to be overwritable; `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` have always been read only.

---

`Infinity` is a property of the global object (`window` is the global object for Javascript run in the browser), whereas `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is a property of the `Number` constructor.

Prior to the 5th Edition of ECMAScript, value properties of the global object were able to be overwritten:

```
Infinity = 123;
Infinity; // 123
```

*The same applies to `undefined` and `NaN`, which are also properties of the global object and used to be overwritable.*

Properties of the `Number` constructor have always been read only:

```
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY = 123;
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // Infinity
```

---

## Specs:

### ECMAScript [1st Edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) (June 1997)

> #### 15.1.1.2 `Infinity`
>
> The initial value of `Infinity` is `+∞`.
>
> #### 15.7.3.6 `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
>
> The value of `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is `+∞`.
>
> This property shall have the attributes { DontEnum, DontDelete, ReadOnly }.

### ECMAScript [5th Edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf) (December 2009)

In ES5, the value properties of the global object were made read only:

> #### 15.1.1.2 `Infinity`
>
> The value of `Infinity` is `+∞` (see 8.5).
>
> This property has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]:` **`false`**`, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`.

The properties of the `Number` constructor didn't really change, but the attributes were renamed:

> #### 15.7.3.6 `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
>
> The value of `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is `+∞`.
>
> This property has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]:` **`false`**`, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`.

**As of ES2018 these definitions have not changed.**

---

## About `isFinite`:

I once posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690071/why-check-for-isnan-after-isfinite) as to why the Google Closure Library implements a custom function for `isFinite`, and the answer was that there was probably some cross-browser inconsistency, although it's unclear which browser and which inconsistency.

Comment: But, you didn't really answer whether `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` gives the same result as `Infinity` other than the fact that `Infinity` is changeable in older browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's not the question if I'm understanding it correctly. It is asking whether there is a reason for using `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` over `Infinity`, and this reason is a legitimate one I think.

Comment: I thought one of the reason you might use one over the other is if they were actually different in some way (e.g. behaved differently in some circurmsntaces).

Comment: They behave differently if `Infinity` has been overwritten :)